# Testing Custom Devise Views in Rails 3 w/ Capybara Request Specs & It Is Not Using the New Custom View

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, capybara

I can open the view after running `rails server` and I see the newly created text field for billing_name as seen below and it works just fine.

views/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<h2>My New Signup</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<p><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></p>

<p><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></p>

<p><%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Password Confirmation' %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

<p><%= f.label :billing_name, 'Billing Name' %><br />
<%= f.text_field :billing_name %></p>

<p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>
```

When I run my specs, however, it appears to be looking at the default devise view and cannot find that newly created billing_name field. If I `save_and_open_page` before trying to access that field in my spec it shows the default devise registration page, even though when I run `rails server -e test`, it displays my new customized view.

Here is the spec:

specs/requests/registration_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Registraion" do
  describe "GET /signup" do
    it "allows signup with proper credentials" do
      visit signup_path

      fill_in "user_email", :with => "sample@email.com"
      fill_in "user_password", :with => "password"
      fill_in "user_password_confirmation", :with => "password"
      save_and_open_page
      fill_in "user_billing_name", :with => "First Last"
    end
  end
end
```

And my spec helper is just the basic one that is auto-generated:

specs/spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you override the Devise controllers, be sure to also override the devise_for routes.

For example (in routes.rb):

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }
```

The Devise wiki also has an [example](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-routes-to-user-registration-pages).